# Web.config rule forces HTTPS even on localhost

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis

I'm trying to enforce HTTPS using a rule in my web.config, except when using localhost. I keep getting this error every time I launch in debug mode:

> An error occurred attempting to determine the process id of dotnet.exe which is hosting your application. An error occurred while sending the request

When I remove the rule from web.config everything works fine. Why doesnt the `pattern=localhost negate=true` line exempt localhost and let everything work correctly? Im using IIS Express from within Visual Studio

```
<!--URL rewrite module must be installed on IIS server for this to work-->
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Redirect to https" enabled="true" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="*" negate="false" />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" />
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="localhost" negate="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

**For anyone who just hit this error and wants a quick solution, create a web.Debug.config and a web.release.config. remove the redirect from the Debug version**

Comment: Is it using the default port? If not you might have to include that in the pattern matching?

Comment: Visual Studio has its own logic to hook to IIS/IIS Express (undocumented unfortunately), and the debugger usually dislikes to be redirected.